# Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens

Tags: java, cookies, http-get, illegalargumentexception

While making http GET request with cookie header to my containerized spring boot application, I am facing the following error which is because of issue in parsing the cookie header

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:422)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:683)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

While making this request through Postman from my ubuntu machine, it works. But when it is called from Postman of any of my colleague's windows machine it throws the error

I have gone through dozen questions relating to this and https is not the reason in my case. I understand that cookie is getting encoded in their machines somehow which the server is reading it plain thus throwing the error on parsing

Can someone please explain the reason for this error ?

PS: Trying to understand the source but GrepCode is down :(

Comment: Could you add some more details about the request that you are making? If you can, just post the URL and headers that you send with postman

Comment: Here is the http request  http://a.b.c.d:8003/xyz/api/v1/abc?id=223 . I am passing an auth cookie . Won't be able to copy the original request

Comment: It is very weird as the same request does not work from other instance postman which has the same setting